# Spark fails with org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Encountered error while reading file xxxxxx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

We are having a parquet file and read it via Spark (3.3.2).  This is a time series data that is collected from a source every 1 hr and we are observing the following error. The surprising thing is that only this parquet is failing - every other collection doesnt seem to have an issue with the spark code.

```
2

3/03/27 10:23:18 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Encountered error while reading file file:///home/..............2.parquet. Details:
            at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFilesError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:713)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:283)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec
..................................

java.io.IOException: can not read class org.apache.parquet.format.PageHeader: Socket is closed by peer.
```

This parquet file is in the "s3 bucket" partitioned by data and time of collection. While querying via s3 query - it is showing the json. When the spark reads the parquet and displays using .show() it is showing the records. However when we do an operator ==== or =!=  like col("isAvailable") === true or col("isAvailable")=!= false is failing.

We have set the following
spark.sql("set spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference=true")
and it shows FileScanRDD: Skipped the rest of the content in the corrupted file: path:

We are clueless why this specific file will show this issue.  We are also observing these issues sporadically - which is causing our tasks to crash.